# generate electricity from cooling tower

Tags: electricity, cooling

I am wondering while there is a reasonable continuous air flow inside the cooling towers from down upward due to the pressure difference between down and up, why we don't use a wind turbine and placed it in lower part of the tower and generate electricity. 
recently there are a few large scale solar updraft tower in different countries that they want to generate hot air and make updraft air flow as it happens in cooling towers and use wind turbine to generate electricity.

how come these two phenomena are the same, but we don't generate electricity in cooling towers?!

Thanks,
Mahmoud

Answer (score 1):

There exist [solar towers or  chimneys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_updraft_tower)  which [produce energy on the same principle.](http://www.brynmawr.edu/geology/206/gruenstein2.htm) [The principle works](http://data.solar-tower.org.uk/pdf/INDIA-A-Solar-Chimney-Power-Plant-TULJAPUR-16p.pdf) and there was also a prototype in Spain and some more in various places.

It has not taken off probably due to the cost of building the structure being not competitive with solar panel energy. The chimneys have to be very high in order to get enough energy out of the system and the [efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_updraft_tower#Efficiency) is not high. A recent [report is here](https://cleantechnica.com/2015/06/30/enviromission-reports-progress-first-solar-chimney-india/).

Answer (score 1):

Any turbine you put inside the cooling tower *must* decrease the flow of air, by necessity. If it's not slowing the air down, it's not taking any energy out of it.  In cooling towers, their primary purpose is to cool, and that's best done by maximizing air flow.